# Преобразование имени файла в url сссылку

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Есть некоторая необходимость скачивать файлы по http с сервера. Проблема в том, что файлы могут содержать спец.символы, которые должны заменяться на их код, например, всем известный пробел на %20, символ номера на %e0 ну и так далее.
Есть готовые функции, если верить интернету, для Шарпа, Пхп, ... Не могу найти для vc++. Не ужели требуется вводить внутренние требования на имена файлов или писать свой конвертер замены спецсимволов для url.

Суть программы в том, что ей передаётся список файлов, она их скачивает с определённого адреса сайта, указанного раздела.

Comment: @pincher1519, прочел повнимательней Ваш вопрос и посмотрел на текст программы. Для кодирования не ASCII символов (судя по вопросу Вас это тоже надо) в функции `pct_encode` замените

    if (isspace(c) || iscntrl(c) || c == '%') {


на

    if (isspace(c) || iscntrl(c) || c == '%' || c > 126) {

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Делал в принципе с другой целью, но возможно Вам подойдет

```
// avp 2013 по мотивам https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.1

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

/*  
    Заменяет isspace() символы и % на %HH
    Input:   ilen байт в char *input
    Result:  байты в char *out максимальной длины osize
             их количество по адресу olen.
    Returns: количство "оттранслированных" байт из input
 */
size_t
pct_encode (const char *input, size_t ilen, 
        char *out, size_t osize, size_t *olen)
{
  size_t i, l;

  for (l = i = 0; i < ilen && l < osize; i++) {
    int c = (unsigned char)input[i];
    if (isspace(c) || iscntrl(c) || c == '%') {
      if (l + 2 < osize) {
    sprintf(out + l, "%%%02X", c);
    l += 3;
      } else    // нет места
    break;
    } else 
      out[l++] = c;
  }

  *olen = l;
  return i;
}

// вызывать только с VALID HEXCODE
static inline int  
hex (int c)
{
  if ('0' <= c && c <= '9')
    c -= '0';
  else if ('A' <= c && c <= 'F')
    c -= ('A' - 10) ;
  else
    c -= ('a' - 10);

  return c;
}

/*  
    Заменяет %HH в тексте на байты
    Input:   ilen байт в char *input
             флаг ignerr - игнорировать ошибки формата %HH
    Result:  байты в char *out максимальной длины osize
             их количество по адресу olen.
    Returns: количство "оттранслированных" байт из input
 */
size_t
pct_decode (const char *input, size_t ilen, 
        char *out, size_t osize, size_t *olen, int ignerr)
{
  size_t i, l;

  for (l = i = 0; i < ilen && l < osize; i++) {
    int c1, c2;
    if (input[i] == '%') {
      if (i + 2 < ilen && 
      isxdigit(c1 = input[i + 1]) && isxdigit(c2 = input[i + 2])) {
    out[l++] = hex(c1) * 16 + hex(c2);
    i += 2;
      } else if (ignerr)
    out[l++] = input[i];
      else
    break;
    } else
      out[l++] = input[i];
  }

  *olen = l;
  return i;
}
```

Comment: @avp, Спасибо, попробуем прогнать функции и сравнить с ожидаемым результатом.

Comment: @avp, Благодарю еще раз, Ваше решение тоже вполне жизнеспособно, но разработчики сделали свои санки, которые прошли все тесты тестировщиков. К сожалению, это самописная реализация и не зависит от изменяемых технологий ОС и интернета. Завтра разрешат писать в именах файлов символ ? или *, и вся логика будет нарушена...